# Adding items in a loop on Python

Tags: python, loops, encoding

So what I'm trying to do is make a code that adds the value of the letters in a name e.g. name: ABCD ---> 1 + 2+ 3+ 4= 10

My code so far is:

```
def main():
    name = input("Please enter your name (all lowercase): ")
    print("\nHere is the code: ")
    for ch in name:
        print(ord(ch)-96,end=" ")
```

What I want to do is add all the values of the `(ord(ch)-96,end=" ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
sum(ord(c) - 96 for c in name)
```

---

**Relevant documentation**

- [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)

Comment: You might want to also explain the [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't actually need to print out the value of each character like you currently are, use `sum` like others have suggested.

However, if you want to keep the loop body which prints out the value of each character as well as summing them all, just create a variable outside the loop and increment it by `ord(c)-96` each time:

```
total = 0
for ch in name:
    charValue = ord(ch)-96
    print(charValue, end="")
    total += charValue
```

Once the for loop is completed `total` will hold the sum of all the values of each character.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [19]: sum(ord(c) - ord('A') + 1 for c in 'ABCD')
Out[19]: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a mapping of char->value, which you can do using a `dict`:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> lookup = {ch:idx for idx, ch in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
>>> test = 'abcd'
>>> sum(lookup[ch] for ch in test)
10
```

This saves mucking about with ordinal values and is a bit more explicit...